# Requiring variables to be declared at or before their first use

Tags: python, type-hinting, python-typing

Python has always allowed you to assign to a new variable with the same syntax that you use to assign to an existing variable. So if you misspell a variable name (or forget to say `global` or `nonlocal`, when you mean to refer to a preexisting but non-local variable), you silently create a new variable.

I know that Python has added more syntactic support for type annotations over the years, and there are various tools that use these to enforce static checks on Python code. But I'm foggy on the details of what's possible. Can you automatically check that all variables are declared with an annotation, so that mistakenly created variables become an error for the type-checker?

Comment: What scope are we talking about here? Module namespace? Class namespace? Local function variables? An entire project?

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Any real scope for which such checks are possible. I don't think Python has a notion of project-wide scopes. The broadest scope there is is a module scope.

Comment: Most type-checkers have a feature like that, for example you can use `mypy --strict`. What tools are you using?

Comment: @Jasmijn Mypy does no such thing, even in `strict` mode. On the contrary, if you assign `x = 1` for the first time, it will infer `x` to be of type `int` automatically. It does not raise errors, if you omit the annotation. It complains if you do not annotate functions though.

Comment: @DaniilFajnberg Fair enough, it will still try to infer unannotated variables (although strict mode will complain if it can't infer the exact type from initial assignment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the module level, you could compare the [global namespace](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#globals) with the module's [`__annotations__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-42) dictionary.

```py
a: int = 1
b: str = "foo"
c: float = 3.14


assert all(name in __annotations__ for name in globals() if not name.startswith("_"))
```

Remove for example the `: float` annotation of `c` and you get an error.

This excludes underscored names since there are a lot of those reserved right away, but you could be more fine-grained of course.

The problem is that this breaks down as soon as you import names from other modules since they obviously do not appear in the importing module's `__annotations__`.

Assuming you never import "plain old variables", but only classes, functions or constants, you could work around this, by additionally excluding callable types or all-caps-names from the check.

```py
from asyncio import run, Task, ALL_COMPLETED

a: int = 1
b: str = "foo"
c: float = 3.14

assert all(
    name in __annotations__
    for name, value in globals().items()
    if not (name.startswith("_") or name.isupper() or callable(value))
)
```

But you would still have to stick this line at the bottom of every module.

You could factor the logic out into a function like this:

```py
from typing import Any


def ensure_everything_annotated(
    namespace: dict[str, Any],
    annotations: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
) -> None:
    if annotations is None:
        annotations = namespace["__annotations__"]
    assert all(
        name in annotations
        for name, value in namespace.items()
        if not (name.startswith("_") or name.isupper() or callable(value))
    )
```

Then you could use it in modules like this:

```py
a: int = 1
b: str = "foo"
c = 3.14

...

ensure_everything_annotated(globals())  # error
```

And with a class like this: ([classes have `__annotations__` of their own](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#index-48))

```py
class Foo:
    spam: str
    eggs: int = -1
    beans = 420.69


ensure_everything_annotated(Foo.__dict__)  # error
```

---

**EDIT**: I just remembered that descriptors (such as [`property`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#property) in a class namespace for example) would also cause this to fail because the descriptor itself may not be callable, so you would have to account for that, too. You could for example check for the existence of a [`__get__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__get__) method on the value as well.

Here is a slightly more sophisticated implementation:

```py
from typing import Any


def ensure_everything_annotated(
    namespace: dict[str, Any],
    annotations: dict[str, Any] | None = None,
) -> None:
    if annotations is None:
        annotations = namespace["__annotations__"]
    for name, value in namespace.items():
        if (
            name.startswith("_")          # exclude protected/private
            or name.isupper()             # exclude constants
            or callable(value)            # exclude functions/classes
            or hasattr(value, "__get__")  # exclude descriptors
        ):
            continue
        if name not in annotations:
            raise TypeError(f"{name} is not annotated")
```

But I suppose the key takeaway here is that it is not immediately obvious how to make such a check **robust**.